# Question about Hilbert–Schmidt operator and its inverse

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I was reading on Hilbert–Schmidt operators, so if I have a bounded linear operator $F \in B(H)$ on a Hilbert space $H$ that is also Hilbert–Schmidt, where I am using the wiki definition.

My question is if I find an inverse in the sense of bounded linear operators, I am thinking it is given to me or I use generalization of Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula to find an inverse, is that inverse going to be necessarily Hilbert–Schmidt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Hilbert-Schmidt operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is *never* invertible.  This follows, for instance, from the fact that the product of a Hilbert-Schmidt operator and any other bounded operator is Hilbert-Schmidt, and the identity operator is not Hilbert-Schmidt.

(Of course, on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, every operator is Hilbert-Schmidt.)

Comment: When I was reading I got the impression, that Hilbert-Schmidt operators form an ideal (the algebraic definition) in the space of the bounded linear operators. Is that true? If so then you are using that idea to say that Hilbert Schmidt operator is never invertable correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: By any chance do you have a reference for that? I think it is not hard to show, but I would like to see it if possible.

Comment: I don't know a reference off the top of my head, but you should be able to find it in any introductory text on operators on Hilbert space.

Comment: Here's a quick sketch: if $(e_i)$ is an orthonormal basis, $A$ is Hilbert-Schmidt, and $B$ is bounded, observe that $\sum \|BAe_i\|^2\leq\sum\|B\|^2\|Ae_i\|^2=\|B\|^2\sum\|Ae_i\|^2<\infty$, so $BA$ is Hilbert-Schmidt.  For compositions on the other side, take adjoints ($A$ is Hilbert-Schmidt iff $A^*$ is).